# How to create a Left Join in Jinzhu GORM

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I can not create a simple query with a left join in jinzhu GORM (MySQL database)

These are my structs:

```
type Prop struct {
    ID          uint   
    Status      Status 
    StatusID    uint
    Name        string 
}

type Status struct {
    ID   uint   
    Name string
}
```

Prop has a foreign key to Status

The SQL query i would like to perform is:

```
SELECT * from prop LEFT JOIN status ON prop.status_id = status.id
```

So i would retrieve all records from prop table joined with status table

I tried:

```
db.Find(&prop).Related(&status)
```

but no Success. Anyone has some advice? Thanks in advance

Comment: here is the official doc of gorm. http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Joins. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: Hey @MarufTuhin i tried that. but the joined table does not come populated: 
`var prop []model.Prop
db.Table("prop").Select("*").Joins("left join status on prop.status_id = status.id").Scan(&prop)`
The result is:
`[
{"id":1,"Status":{"id":0,"name":""},"StatusID":1,"name":"Proposal},{"id":2,"Status":{"id":0,"name":""},"StatusID":2,"name":"Proposal 2"}
`]
As you can see Status object returns empty

Comment: I just read somewhere that, table needs to be preloaded. Try preloading the `status` table here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey @arthur_mastropietro,
I think Preloading the `Prop`'s related `Status` is the key. Try the below:

```
prop := Prop{}
if err := db.Model(&prop).Preload("Status").Find(&prop).Error; err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", prop)
```

### Note

You can chain the preloading of other structs, ie 
`Preload("Status").Preload("Something").`..etc. In fact you can chain most `Gorm` function calls.

Additionally, if `Status` was to also have another struct as one of it's fields you can load them both at once by calling
`Preload("Status.Something")`

Hope that helps!